# I don’t understand how the values in this Excel table are generated

Tags: microsoft-excel

I watch this [video tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCF-Btu5ZCk) and I don’t understand how the values in this Excel table are generated. The author types in a function and selected blank columns.

Yet the values appear afterwards?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### A formula is applied across those cells.

#### The creator of the video is actively typing in the formula while explaining it and then doesn’t pause long enough to let you see the final product.

Agreed. This is hard to see if you are not paying attention, and even if you do pay attention, since the tutorial is not really pausing to explain.

But the person who created this tutorial is creating a formula and applying it to the whole block of cells you see.

Look at this screenshot below from [about 6:09 into the video](https://youtu.be/jCF-Btu5ZCk?t=363). Look at the formula above the cells from about `AG` to `AJ`. Note they are actively typing in a formal which is this:

```
=(sum(D11:K11)+4*L11+AH11)/13)
```

Note they are typing so quickly, they didn’t even show the final formula with the closing parenthesis; I manually added that since I know it should be there.

What they are doing is copying and pasting that exact formula from row `10` to row `15` and across columns `B` to about `A5`.

By doing this, the formula will apply itself across different values.

[image]

Comment: I understand the formula and that its applied across different cells by dragging the cross. But the cells have empty values? How can number appear from applying a formula to empty values in cells?